# Bootstrap Radio button alignment with rest of the form.

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The problem is getting the radio buttons and their labels to line up while also aligning with the rest of the form. I am new to this.I am trying to make radio buttons align with the rest of the form and somehow reached here.
Please help me to make it right.

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
   <form class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
         <p class="text-center">Gift Information</p>
         <br>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="control-group">
            <div class="text">
               <label for="giftamount" class="control-label col-xs">Select Gift Amount</label>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-10">
            <div class="radio">
               <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-2">
                  <input type="radio" name="giftamount" value="$30.00">  $30.00
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
               <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-2">
                  <input type="radio" name="giftamount" value="$75.00">   $75.00
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
               <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-2">
                  <input type="radio" name="giftamount" value="$100.00">  $100.00
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
               <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-2">
                  <input type="radio" name="giftamount" value="">Surprise Me
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-2">
               <label for="Gift amount" class="control-label">Enter the amount</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="giftamount" name="giftamount" placeholder="Enter the amount">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <p class="text-center">Billing Information</p>
         <br>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="fname" class="control-label col-xs-2">First Name</label>
         <div class="col-xs-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="FirstName">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="mname" class="control-label col-xs-2">Middle Name</label>
         <div class="col-xs-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mname"
               placeholder="MiddleName" />
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="lname" class="control-label col-xs-2">Last Name</label>
         <div class="col-xs-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname"
               placeholder="LastName" />
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="street1" class="control-label col-xs-2">Street1</label>
         <div class="col-xs-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="street1"
               placeholder="Street1" />
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="street2" class="control-label col-xs-2">Street2</label>
         <div class="col-xs-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="street2"
               placeholder="Street2" />
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="city" class="control-label col-xs-2">City</label>
         <div class="col-xs-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" placeholder="City" />
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="mname" class="control-label col-xs-2">State/Province</label>
         <div class="col-xs-2">
            <select name='state' class="form-control">
               <option value=''>Choose a State</option>
               <option value='AK'>Alaska</option>
               <option value='AL'>Alabama</option>
               <option value='AR'>Arkansas</option>
               <option value='AZ'>Arizona</option>
               <option value='CA'>California</option>
               <option value='CO'>Colorado</option>
               <option value='CT'>Connecticut</option>
               <option value='DC'>District of Columbia</option>
               <option value='DE'>Delaware</option>
               <option value='FL'>Florida</option>
               <option value='GA'>Georgia</option>
               <option value='HI'>Hawaii</option>
               <option value='IA'>Iowa</option>
               <option value='ID'>Idaho</option>
               <option value='IL'>Illinois</option>
               <option value='IN'>Indiana</option>
               <option value='KS'>Kansas</option>
               <option value='KY'>Kentucky</option>
               <option value='LA'>Louisiana</option>
               <option value='MA'>Massachusetts</option>
               <option value='MD'>Maryland</option>
               <option value='ME'>Maine</option>
               <option value='MI'>Michigan</option>
               <option value='MN'>Minnesota</option>
               <option value='MO'>Missouri</option>
               <option value='MS'>Mississippi</option>
               <option value='MT'>Montana</option>
               <option value='NC'>North Carolina</option>
               <option value='ND'>North Dakota</option>
               <option value='NE'>Nebraska</option>
               <option value='NH'>New Hampshire</option>
               <option value='NJ'>New Jersey</option>
               <option value='NM'>New Mexico</option>
               <option value='NV'>Nevada</option>
               <option value='NY'>New York</option>
               <option value='OH'>Ohio</option>
               <option value='OK'>Oklahoma</option>
               <option value='OR'>Oregon</option>
               <option value='PA'>Pennsylvania</option>
               <option value='PR'>Puerto Rico</option>
               <option value='RI'>Rhode Island</option>
               <option value='SC'>South Carolina</option>
               <option value='SD'>South Dakota</option>
               <option value='TN'>Tennessee</option>
               <option value='TX'>Texas</option>
               <option value='UT'>Utah</option>
               <option value='VA'>Virginia</option>
               <option value='VT'>Vermont</option>
               <option value='WA'>Washington</option>
               <option value='WI'>Wisconsin</option>
               <option value='WV'>West Virginia</option>
               <option value='WY'>Wyoming</option>
               <option value='' style="font-weight: bold;">- Canadian Provinces</option>
               <option value='AB'>Alberta</option>
               <option value='BC'>British Columbia</option>
               <option value='MB'>Manitoba</option>
               <option value='NB'>New Brunswick</option>
               <option value='NF'>Newfoundland</option>
               <option value='NT'>Northwest Territories</option>
               <option value='NS'>Nova Scotia</option>
               <option value='NU'>Nunavut</option>
               <option value='ON'>Ontario</option>
               <option value='PE'>Prince Edward Island</option>
               <option value='QC'>Quebec</option>
               <option value='SK'>Saskatchewan</option>
               <option value='YT'>Yukon Territory</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="zip" class="control-label col-xs-2">Zip/Postal code</label>
         <div class="col-xs-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zip" placeholder="######" />
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="ph_number" class="control-label col-xs-2">Phone Number</label>
         <div class="col-xs-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ph_number" placeholder="number with country code" />
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="email" class="control-label col-xs-2">Email Address</label>
         <div class="col-xs-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="abc@domain.com" />
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="Country" class="control-label col-xs-2">Country</label>
         <div class="col-xs-2">
            <select name='country' class="form-control">
               <option value=''>Choose a Country</option>
               <option value="Afganistan">Afghanistan</option>
               <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
               <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
               <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
               <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
               <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
               <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
               <option value="Antigua &amp; Barbuda">Antigua &amp; Barbuda</option>
               <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
               <option value="Armenia">Armenia</option>
               <option value="Aruba">Aruba</option>
               <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
               <option value="Austria">Austria</option>
               <option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>
               <option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option>
               <option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
               <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
               <option value="Barbados">Barbados</option>
               <option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
               <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
               <option value="Belize">Belize</option>
               <option value="Benin">Benin</option>
               <option value="Bermuda">Bermuda</option>
               <option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
               <option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option>
               <option value="Bonaire">Bonaire</option>
               <option value="Bosnia &amp; Herzegovina">Bosnia &amp; Herzegovina</option>
               <option value="Botswana">Botswana</option>
               <option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
               <option value="British Indian Ocean Ter">British Indian Ocean Ter</option>
               <option value="Brunei">Brunei</option>
               <option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option>
               <option value="Burkina Faso">Burkina Faso</option>
               <option value="Burundi">Burundi</option>
               <option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>
               <option value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option>
               <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
               <option value="Canary Islands">Canary Islands</option>
               <option value="Cape Verde">Cape Verde</option>
               <option value="Cayman Islands">Cayman Islands</option>
               <option value="Central African Republic">Central African Republic</option>
               <option value="Chad">Chad</option>
               <option value="Channel Islands">Channel Islands</option>
               <option value="Chile">Chile</option>
               <option value="China">China</option>
               <option value="Christmas Island">Christmas Island</option>
               <option value="Cocos Island">Cocos Island</option>
               <option value="Colombia">Colombia</option>
               <option value="Comoros">Comoros</option>
               <option value="Congo">Congo</option>
               <option value="Cook Islands">Cook Islands</option>
               <option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option>
               <option value="Cote DIvoire">Cote D'Ivoire</option>
               <option value="Croatia">Croatia</option>
               <option value="Cuba">Cuba</option>
               <option value="Curaco">Curacao</option>
               <option value="Cyprus">Cyprus</option>
               <option value="Czech Republic">Czech Republic</option>
               <option value="Denmark">Denmark</option>
               <option value="Djibouti">Djibouti</option>
               <option value="Dominica">Dominica</option>
               <option value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option>
               <option value="East Timor">East Timor</option>
               <option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option>
               <option value="Egypt">Egypt</option>
               <option value="El Salvador">El Salvador</option>
               <option value="Equatorial Guinea">Equatorial Guinea</option>
               <option value="Eritrea">Eritrea</option>
               <option value="Estonia">Estonia</option>
               <option value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</option>
               <option value="Falkland Islands">Falkland Islands</option>
               <option value="Faroe Islands">Faroe Islands</option>
               <option value="Fiji">Fiji</option>
               <option value="Finland">Finland</option>
               <option value="France">France</option>
               <option value="French Guiana">French Guiana</option>
               <option value="French Polynesia">French Polynesia</option>
               <option value="French Southern Ter">French Southern Ter</option>
               <option value="Gabon">Gabon</option>
               <option value="Gambia">Gambia</option>
               <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
               <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
               <option value="Ghana">Ghana</option>
               <option value="Gibraltar">Gibraltar</option>
               <option value="Great Britain">Great Britain</option>
               <option value="Greece">Greece</option>
               <option value="Greenland">Greenland</option>
               <option value="Grenada">Grenada</option>
               <option value="Guadeloupe">Guadeloupe</option>
               <option value="Guam">Guam</option>
               <option value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option>
               <option value="Guinea">Guinea</option>
               <option value="Guyana">Guyana</option>
               <option value="Haiti">Haiti</option>
               <option value="Hawaii">Hawaii</option>
               <option value="Honduras">Honduras</option>
               <option value="Hong Kong">Hong Kong</option>
               <option value="Hungary">Hungary</option>
               <option value="Iceland">Iceland</option>
               <option value="India">India</option>
               <option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option>
               <option value="Iran">Iran</option>
               <option value="Iraq">Iraq</option>
               <option value="Ireland">Ireland</option>
               <option value="Isle of Man">Isle of Man</option>
               <option value="Israel">Israel</option>
               <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
               <option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option>
               <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
               <option value="Jordan">Jordan</option>
               <option value="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</option>
               <option value="Kenya">Kenya</option>
               <option value="Kiribati">Kiribati</option>
               <option value="Korea North">Korea North</option>
               <option value="Korea Sout">Korea South</option>
               <option value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option>
               <option value="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</option>
               <option value="Laos">Laos</option>
               <option value="Latvia">Latvia</option>
               <option value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option>
               <option value="Lesotho">Lesotho</option>
               <option value="Liberia">Liberia</option>
               <option value="Libya">Libya</option>
               <option value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option>
               <option value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option>
               <option value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
               <option value="Macau">Macau</option>
               <option value="Macedonia">Macedonia</option>
               <option value="Madagascar">Madagascar</option>
               <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
               <option value="Malawi">Malawi</option>
               <option value="Maldives">Maldives</option>
               <option value="Mali">Mali</option>
               <option value="Malta">Malta</option>
               <option value="Marshall Islands">Marshall Islands</option>
               <option value="Martinique">Martinique</option>
               <option value="Mauritania">Mauritania</option>
               <option value="Mauritius">Mauritius</option>
               <option value="Mayotte">Mayotte</option>
               <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
               <option value="Midway Islands">Midway Islands</option>
               <option value="Moldova">Moldova</option>
               <option value="Monaco">Monaco</option>
               <option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
               <option value="Montserrat">Montserrat</option>
               <option value="Morocco">Morocco</option>
               <option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option>
               <option value="Myanmar">Myanmar</option>
               <option value="Nambia">Nambia</option>
               <option value="Nauru">Nauru</option>
               <option value="Nepal">Nepal</option>
               <option value="Netherland Antilles">Netherland Antilles</option>
               <option value="Netherlands">Netherlands (Holland, Europe)</option>
               <option value="Nevis">Nevis</option>
               <option value="New Caledonia">New Caledonia</option>
               <option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
               <option value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option>
               <option value="Niger">Niger</option>
               <option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option>
               <option value="Niue">Niue</option>
               <option value="Norfolk Island">Norfolk Island</option>
               <option value="Norway">Norway</option>
               <option value="Oman">Oman</option>
               <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
               <option value="Palau Island">Palau Island</option>
               <option value="Palestine">Palestine</option>
               <option value="Panama">Panama</option>
               <option value="Papua New Guinea">Papua New Guinea</option>
               <option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option>
               <option value="Peru">Peru</option>
               <option value="Phillipines">Philippines</option>
               <option value="Pitcairn Island">Pitcairn Island</option>
               <option value="Poland">Poland</option>
               <option value="Portugal">Portugal</option>
               <option value="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico</option>
               <option value="Qatar">Qatar</option>
               <option value="Republic of Montenegro">Republic of Montenegro</option>
               <option value="Republic of Serbia">Republic of Serbia</option>
               <option value="Reunion">Reunion</option>
               <option value="Romania">Romania</option>
               <option value="Russia">Russia</option>
               <option value="Rwanda">Rwanda</option>
               <option value="St Barthelemy">St Barthelemy</option>
               <option value="St Eustatius">St Eustatius</option>
               <option value="St Helena">St Helena</option>
               <option value="St Kitts-Nevis">St Kitts-Nevis</option>
               <option value="St Lucia">St Lucia</option>
               <option value="St Maarten">St Maarten</option>
               <option value="St Pierre &amp; Miquelon">St Pierre &amp; Miquelon</option>
               <option value="St Vincent &amp; Grenadines">St Vincent &amp;
                  Grenadines
               </option>
               <option value="Saipan">Saipan</option>
               <option value="Samoa">Samoa</option>
               <option value="Samoa American">Samoa American</option>
               <option value="San Marino">San Marino</option>
               <option value="Sao Tome &amp; Principe">Sao Tome &amp; Principe</option>
               <option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
               <option value="Senegal">Senegal</option>
               <option value="Serbia">Serbia</option>
               <option value="Seychelles">Seychelles</option>
               <option value="Sierra Leone">Sierra Leone</option>
               <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
               <option value="Slovakia">Slovakia</option>
               <option value="Slovenia">Slovenia</option>
               <option value="Solomon Islands">Solomon Islands</option>
               <option value="Somalia">Somalia</option>
               <option value="South Africa">South Africa</option>
               <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
               <option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
               <option value="Sudan">Sudan</option>
               <option value="Suriname">Suriname</option>
               <option value="Swaziland">Swaziland</option>
               <option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
               <option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
               <option value="Syria">Syria</option>
               <option value="Tahiti">Tahiti</option>
               <option value="Taiwan">Taiwan</option>
               <option value="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</option>
               <option value="Tanzania">Tanzania</option>
               <option value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
               <option value="Togo">Togo</option>
               <option value="Tokelau">Tokelau</option>
               <option value="Tonga">Tonga</option>
               <option value="Trinidad &amp; Tobago">Trinidad &amp; Tobago</option>
               <option value="Tunisia">Tunisia</option>
               <option value="Turkey">Turkey</option>
               <option value="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option>
               <option value="Turks &amp; Caicos Is">Turks &amp; Caicos Is</option>
               <option value="Tuvalu">Tuvalu</option>
               <option value="Uganda">Uganda</option>
               <option value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option>
               <option value="United Arab Erimates">United Arab Emirates</option>
               <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
               <option value="United States of America">United States of America</option>
               <option value="Uraguay">Uruguay</option>
               <option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>
               <option value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option>
               <option value="Vatican City State">Vatican City State</option>
               <option value="Venezuela">Venezuela</option>
               <option value="Vietnam">Vietnam</option>
               <option value="Virgin Islands (Brit)">Virgin Islands (Brit)</option>
               <option value="Virgin Islands (USA)">Virgin Islands (USA)</option>
               <option value="Wake Island">Wake Island</option>
               <option value="Wallis &amp; Futana Is">Wallis &amp; Futana Is</option>
               <option value="Yemen">Yemen</option>
               <option value="Zaire">Zaire</option>
               <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
               <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row fluid">
         <div class="span6 offset6 ">
            <div class="formgroup">
               <div class="radio">
                  <label for="Gift amount" class="control-label col-xs-2"><input type="radio" name="giftamount" value="$30.00">$30.00</label>
               </div>
               <div class="radio">
                  <label for="Gift amount" class="control-label col-xs-2"><input type="radio" name="giftamount" value="$75.00">$75.00</label>
               </div>
               <div class="radio">
                  <label for="Gift amount" class="control-label col-xs-2"><input type="radio" name="giftamount" value="$100.00">$100.00</label>
               </div>
               <div class="radio">
                  <label for="Gift amount" class="control-label col-xs-2"><input type="radio" name="giftamount" value="">Surprise Me</label>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-2">
            <div class="checkbox">
               <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </form>
</body>
```

Comment: In future, please reduce your code down to a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by

```
col-xs-offset-3
```

which is added as every radio button's class here. Offset-3 gives an element 3 cells (3 units out of 12 in Bootstrap grid layout) left margin. That's why it is so indented. Try replacing every:

```
<div class="radio">
               <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-2">
               ...
```

with

```
<div class="radio">
               <div class="col-xs-2">
               ...
```

[image]

Comment: yeah may be this is the root cause then what should i do or change in the code to make it align with the rest of the form.

Comment: Read my answer once again, everything is there.

Comment: yeah try this now all radio buttons are align left most corner not as the rest  of the form.

Comment: Oh, man, your code is completely messed up as far as I can see, post a JSFiddle here, because reading this code is nothing pleasant, for real.

Comment: In this fiddle everything is in one-line with form, so what is wrong now?

Comment: For me it is already aligned to the left, all in one line (edited my answer, take look at the image)

Comment: its worked. thanks for answer.yeah i will surely take care of that.thanks again